# How to give session only if authenticated? Any other middleware order won't work

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js

I have this issue where a session is created regardless if the user is logged in or not.

I would like it if a session is created only if the user logs in successfully. Otherwise, if a selenium bot hits...for example, the route `route('/users/:username')` my session collection would fill up with sessions that are not from real users. I am having my users stay logged in forever, so the session cookie is set to a year...which is even worse if the session does not belong to real user.

How can I have a session returned to the client only if the authenticate successfully? I tried different order of the routes and middle ware, but this is the only order that works correctly.

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'bob',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  name: 'curves',
  cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  store: new MongoStore(storeOptions)
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', auth);
app.use('/api/v1', router);

// isLoggedIn WOULD NOT WORK IF I PLACED THIS BEFORE PASSPORT/SESSION MIDDLEWARE
router.route('/users/:username')
  .get(isLoggedIn, api.getUsername);

auth.route('/auth/facebook')
  .get(passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

auth.route('/auth/facebook/callback')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, userDoc, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      // I don't think !userDoc will ever happen because of mongo upsert
      if (!userDoc) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
      req.logIn(userDoc, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.redirect('http://localhost:9000/users');
      });
  })(req, res, next);
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.status(404).json({ error: "not logged in" });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...I just needed to set `saveUninitialized: false`.

> saveUninitialized
>   Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified. Choosing false is useful for implementing login sessions, reducing server storage usage, or complying with laws that require permission before setting a cookie. Choosing false will also help with race conditions where a client makes multiple parallel requests without a session.
>
> The default value is true, but using the default has been deprecated, as the default will change in the future. Please research into this setting and choose what is appropriate to your use-case.
>
> Note if you are using Session in conjunction with PassportJS, Passport will add an empty Passport object to the session for use after a user is authenticated, which will be treated as a modification to the session, causing it to be saved.